# How to get content of iframe from aws s3

Tags: javascript, iframe, amazon-s3

I want to change attribute of iframe content which is accessed from S3 with public read permission.

```
$('#iframeid').contents().find('Viewpoint#id').attr('set_bind', 'true');
```

But it gives an error

> Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from
>   'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost"
>   from accessing a cross-origin frame.

I already set the CORS rule of bucket

```
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
```

Is there any way, I can set the attributes of iframe content comes from S3?

Comment: Do you control the code inside the iframe?

Comment: I want to control the code inside the iframe

Comment: If you don't have any control over the code on that page inside the frame you can not access inside the iframe unless your page is on same domain.

Comment: Before that iframe url was from same origin at that time my script code worked fine but as i change it to s3 it gives an error

Comment: My xhtml file display in iframe perfectly which is on s3. but only issue is i can't set the attribut of any tag of this xhtml file by jquery

Comment: Right...and you won't be able to unless you can add code inside that iframe page if the main page is not on same domain. That is how same origin policy works with regard to frames

Comment: If this is not possible then i need to move from s3 to my server

Comment: Is there any way to display and control content without iframe?

Comment: Of course there is

Comment: The problem here **may be** that `localhost` is not something CORS will work with, because (presumably) localhost is a specially-reserved hostname that could be anywhere/everywhere.  I've seen it, but haven't found a solid explanation of it.  Access your localhost site with either `http://lvh.me`, or `http://www.127.0.0.1.xip.io`, instead of `http://localhost`.  These are aliases for localhost that look like real domains and this *may* prompt CORS to work as expected.

Comment: I tried it on server also but same error